# How do I avoid a blank screen when Android's browser visits an inline PDF?

Tags: android, pdf

I'm developing a web application for Android phones and I've noticed PDF links with server-sent `Content-Disposition: inline` open a blank browser window, and that's it. I can serve them as downloads but it is awkward to have to open the file after it has downloaded.

Can Android's browser launch (Adobe's) PDF reader when it encounters an inline PDF?